# How to adapt content to a fixed bottom container?

Tags: html, css

I have a container with position fixed at the bottom of the page, and I would like that the content above it (a long paragraph in this case) will be visible to its end when scrolling until the bottom.

I created a working example of this on Codepen: https://codepen.io/omerh3/pen/JjLXdpP

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A saepe repudiandae consequatur id? Dicta eaque, unde maxime deserunt harum modi ex nobis impedit tempora dolor sit laborum voluptates repellat pariatur consequatur perferendis sed laudantium cumque laboriosam, necessitatibus culpa provident, delectus natus dolorem? Fugit ducimus quos eligendi ratione dicta voluptatum error.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-content">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
p {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

.bottom-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

This is working thanks to margin-bottom: 500px, however since it's hard coded, when resizing the width of the page, the height of the content of the bottom container will naturally increase, and the above content won't be fully seen.
How can I dynamically adapt the above content so it's always completely visible when scrolling to the bottom?

Media queries are of course an option but I'm curious to find out if there's a more elegant way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `min-height: 100vh;` instead of `margin-bottom: 500px;` on your **.content** class. Then change `position:fixed` to `position:sticky` in **.bottom-content** and add a global CSS reset class.

```css
/* reset CSS */
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* new parent class */
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 100%; /* new line */
  /* margin-bottom: 500px; */
}

.bottom-content {
  position: sticky; /* changed */
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* new parent class*/
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

p {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 100%; /* new line */
  /* margin-bottom: 500px; */
}

.bottom-content {
  position: sticky; /* changed */
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A saepe repudiandae consequatur id? Dicta eaque, unde maxime deserunt harum modi ex nobis impedit tempora dolor sit laborum voluptates repellat pariatur consequatur perferendis sed laudantium cumque
      laboriosam, necessitatibus culpa provident, delectus natus dolorem? Fugit ducimus quos eligendi ratione dicta voluptatum error.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-content">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying your solution which looks very neat, but facing a problem - even when there's barely content, there will be a vertical scroller. For example if you remove the paragraph, it will still let you scroll through blank space. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Yep, `min-height: 100vh;` will fill all screen space, which means that if there is no content, height will keeps the size. If we using `position: sticky` on the secondary element, this will push it out of the screen viewport and we will get scrolling. Now I've fix it with flofbox. Try this solution.

Comment: That works perfectly thank you very much , very simple and elegant

Answer (score 2):

This is a pattern I use very often. I create a `flex column` as the parent, then have what I call a "dynamic body" class that grows to the available space and scrolls internally by setting `flex-grow: 1; overflow: auto;` . this allows me to put elements above or below (search, header, footer, etc) and the main body section just "fills" in height to adapt.

Mind the height of your container `column` though... it needs to be defined somehow. In this demo I just set it as `position: fixed` and set it to the height and width of the window.

See -

```css
p {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1rem red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid .5rem yellow;
}

.bottom-content {
  border: solid .5rem limegreen;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A saepe repudiandae consequatur id? Dicta eaque, unde maxime deserunt harum modi ex nobis impedit tempora dolor sit laborum voluptates repellat pariatur consequatur perferendis sed laudantium cumque laboriosam, necessitatibus culpa provident, delectus natus dolorem? Fugit ducimus quos eligendi ratione dicta voluptatum error.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-content">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>A</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See example https://codepen.io/jcgilmore2/pen/QWmNbPV